# Does paid parking require official signs?

Tags: european-union, parking, sweden

I recently got ticketed for parking in a parking spot that is, supposedly, paid parking. The only official sign on the premises is the generic "P" sign that, unless I'm mistaken, means I can park there freely for up to 24h. The only sign on the premises that says anything about paid parking is a ***paper*** plaque (facing away from the entrance, no less...) that says "you need to pay for parking starting from October 1st".

I disputed the ticket with the issuer but they said that according to "tax laws" (why would *tax* laws mention this?) this signage is completely legal. When I asked them to tell me which law so I could look it up they ceased communications.

Here's an image of the sign (click to enlarge) and translation for any non-swedish speaking readers:

> Parkingfees on {redacted} from October 1st. Same fee applies within the entire area, payment is issued through the {redacted} app or our ticketless parking meters.

[image: sign image]

This company is known for ticketing **emergency vehicles on-call** (most recently an ambulance responding to a heart attack) so I'm already extremely suspicious of their business.

Comment: Did you park on or after October 1st, i.e. "starting from October 1st"?

Comment: @Brandin After, but this question is more about if the sign is valid to begin with.

Comment: Well it seems like it was pretty clear about the rules, and you violated them anyway. So I don't understand what your question is about. How could it be more clear or official?

Comment: @Brandin I don't understand what the difference between this sign, and me just printing out an A1 sheet of paper and writing the same thing just "for fun" or whatever. I don't know if you're Swedish or not, but in Sweden all parking signs I have ever seen in my entire life are issued by the same people that issue all the other road signs (stop, warning, speed limit, etc.). So these would count as "official". This is just a sign the people that own the parking lot put up, and I have never ever seen something like this before. There's always a state(?)-issued sign, never a private sign.

Comment: Yes, but the other suspicious thing is that you knew ahead of time that they would likely not want you to park in their lot without paying a fee (since you said they have ticketed emergency vehicles for parking there), yet you still parked there anyway. It sounds like you are trying to find some kind of technicality to make it OK what you did without paying. And for this you probably should hire a lawyer, and pay the lawyer. So either way you will have to pay someone.

Comment: I found that out after I googled their business name to dispute the ticket, of course... I didn't write all the info in this post but the parking in question has been free for years (it's a uni parking lot) and it has just recently changed to paid parking. This took lots of people by surprise since almost no-one notices the plaque (like I said, it's a uni so there are TONS of plaques hanging around advertising events and whatnot, PLUS since Sweden is so far north it gets dark at around 3pm, it's almost impossible to see black-on-white signs in headlights) and everyone is extremely upset.

Comment: Many parking places are totally free of charge. The necessity of paying must be made clear to those that do park. A mere piece of paper facing away from the entrance may or may not count as obvious, and consumer protection laws are likely to be implicated here.